# Highcharts - slow dynamic graphic after a while time ANDROID

Tags: android, kotlin, highcharts

I am doing a dynamic graph on Android, with a line and an aeraspline (with zones colors).

Every second, I update my two data tables, which I re-inject into the line and areaspline data.
I then update the minimum and maximum of the x, y1 and y2 axes. To finally update the chart with the update method (chartsOptions, true, true).

Here is the code called every second:

```
enter code here  private fun updateDataChart(chartView: HIChartView, elapsedTimeInSecond: Int, secondMin: Int) {

    // remove zone if too zones
    if (arrayListElevation.size > 1) {
        if (arrayListElevation[0][0] < secondMin && arrayListElevation[1][0] < secondMin) {
            arrayListElevation.removeAt(0)
            listZones.removeAt(0)
        }

    }

    if (equipment!!.type != Equipment.EQUIPMENT_TYPE.TYPE_ROWING_MACHINE) {
        // Setup color zones for areaSpline
        if (oldSlope != currentSlope) {// if change slope
            createLastZone(elapsedTimeInSecond) // create new zone
        } else {// else update value of old zone
            updateLastZone(elapsedTimeInSecond)
        }
    }
    areaSpline.data = arrayListElevation
    line.data = arrayListPower

    // Set min and max time axis
    optionsCharts.xAxis[0].max = secondMin + maxTimeDisplay
    optionsCharts.xAxis[0].min = secondMin
    series[0].zones = listZones

    //Set max elevation
    if (currentElevation > maxElevation) {
        maxElevation += 60
        optionsCharts.yAxis[1].max = maxElevation
    }

    chartView.options = optionsCharts
    chartView.setWillNotDraw(false)
    chartView.update(optionsCharts,true,true)

    oldSlope = currentSlope
}
```

Do you have any idea why the graphic is taking longer and longer to draw?

Does data line and areaspline keep cached data?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: You do not have said how many rows/data you're using each cycle to calculations, so if the rows/records are millions there could be a Reason for your question, but if the data are only 4 Integers the reason could be wlsewhere.....

Comment: From the Highcharts site, it's hard to say what could have an impact on it. Have you tried to disable the animation?

Comment: I add two points and remove two more points per second ....
Yes I have deactivated the animations, the markers ...
What is strange is that it works great for 15mn and after that it starts to lag.